# Getting Live HeartRate from Apple Watch in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, healthkit

In my app, I'm wanting to use the users live heart rate data from the Apple Watch. How would I go about setting up something like this? It would not be running in the background. It would be simultaneously triggered when the user presses a button. I'm currently unaware as to where I would begin.

Comment: Always start with the documentation for the framework. Apple also has all the WWDC videos in the Developer App that usually include sample code. HealthKit and workouts are well documented you will find all you need if you search for those.